What can you say that has the same meaning as "Also, ..." at the beginning of a sentence?
When switching topics or asking an additional question in English, you usually start with "also". Like someone might ask "What movie do you want to see?" and then say "Also, what time are we planning to go?" Is there a word that goes at the beginning like "also" in Japanese?

Usually?  I'm not sure I ever speak this way.  It sounds a bit potentially patronizing and condescending (particularly because you switched from "you" to "we").  I've noticed a trend among young folk using "we" when they mean "you".  But, it sounds like how you would talk to a child, not an adult.

@A.Ellett My guess is that the example is in the context of e.g. two people organizing a trip to see a movie together, in which case it sounds entirely natural to me.

One of these:

どの映画みる？あと、何時に会う？
今、ひま？それと、タピオカは好き？
彼は悪くないよ。それに、どのみち遅刻してたさ。

I was gonna add さらに and そのうえ, but I think these translate better to "on top of that".
